# How to fit a image into css-grid without stretching

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]**Problem:**
The IMG is stretching the css-grid, and I want the image to scale-down and fit into the grid.

**Tried:**
I have tried setting a max-height/width on the image, but it only reduces the stretching of the image.

```css
.grid-container {
display:grid;
grid-template-areas:
"nav_bar"
"main"
"about"
"port_over"
"resu_proj"
"links";
background-color: #161616;
grid-row-gap: 5em;
}

/*Nav bar grid*/
.nav_bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: nav_bar;
    grid-template-areas: "nav_img nav_links nav_links nav_links";
}

/*Nav bar img*/
.nav_img {
    grid-area: nav_img;
    object-fit: cover;

    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
     <div class="nav_bar">

     <img src="./MLW_IMAGES/M.L.W logo.png" class="nav_img">


     <div class="nav_links">
          <nav>
             <a href="/index.html#about">About</a>
             <a href="/index.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
             <a href="/index.html#contact">Contact</a>
          </nav>
     </div>
     </div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: you need to display the  whole image ? in smaller size without streching it ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the width , height to auto?

Comment: Include the images, so we can see the problem.

Comment: @XxSTREKxX I need to display the whole image but scale it down into the grid box.

Comment: @WaqasAmjad I tried setting the width/height to auto and the image reverted back to the original size.

Comment: @Michael_B I included the image of the website. Would you like me to include an image of the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one class for only image. Give particular height and width to image class and give below css to image.

```
.class-name img {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I copied the max/min-height/width code into the class and the image was not affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting max-height and max-width and specify a width you want the image to take if the image size is larger.
is this what you are expecting ?

```css
.grid-container {
display:grid;
grid-template-areas:
"nav_bar"
"main"
"about"
"port_over"
"resu_proj"
"links";
grid-row-gap: 5em;
}

/*Nav bar grid*/
.nav_bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: nav_bar;
    grid-template-areas: "nav_img nav_links nav_links nav_links";
}

/*Nav bar img*/
.nav_img {
    grid-area: nav_img;
    object-fit: cover;

    background-color: grey;
}
img
{
max-height:100px;
max-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
     <div class="nav_bar">

     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" class="nav_img">


     <div class="nav_links">
          <nav>
             <a href="/index.html#about">About</a>
             <a href="/index.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
             <a href="/index.html#contact">Contact</a>
          </nav>
     </div>
     </div>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In responsive context:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* grid */

.grid-element img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style "align-items: start"; to the grid container.